# Unable to access network on Windows Server 2012 (Ethernet)

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows, ethernet

We have a server that had been using Ethernet, but temporarily Wi-Fi, and is now using Ethernet again. Strangely, it will not connect to the Internet.

It detects when a cable is plugged into the port and the driver seems to be working and it is up-to-date.

One particular source of concern which might be the problem is that IPv4 is not selected:

[image: Ethernet Properties ss]

Then, when I try to enable this, I get this error:

```
  Your current selection will also disable the following features:

  Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)

  Are you sure you want to disable these feature(s) ?
```

What else can I try to get this network connection working? I also have Hyper-V setup on this machine, but I have currently disabled the Virtual Adapters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I also have Hyper-V setup on this machine, but I have currently disabled the Virtual Adapters.

This is your problem. Hyper-V takes over the NIC. If you want the Host VM to connect to the NIC again then you need to allow the management operating system to share this network adapter in the Virtual Swit manager for that network in Hyper-V.